# apache2 .htm extension

Tags: apache2

Since I've installed LAMP stack on ubuntu server with apache2, I've been having a weird issue. Whenever I create a file called filename.html, it renders and displays on browser fine. But whenever I create file with extension .htm, it will prompt the browser (firefox) to save the file.

I've already looked into /etc/mime.types and /etc/apache2/mod-enabled/mime.load

Comment: Have you tried other browsers and/or other client platforms? (That is, are you sure it is a server-side issue and not a client-side issue?)

Answer (score 1):

And what's in these files for .htm extension? 
Can you check what mime-type returned by the Apache? (via browser plugins/sniffer)

After that you will see the issue...